# AspectJ aspect not weaving Spring MVC methods with @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have a standalone aspectJ library ( not related to spring in any way) that I added to app server classpath to monitor the running applications using Load Time Weaving

The aspect work perfectly with all methods ( domain, service, DAO...) but for some reason it doesn't recognize Spring MVC methods with @RequestMapping annotation
even if the pointcut expression is matching the controller class and the method name

Is there a different rule for Spring MVC controllers mapping methods ( or Controllers in general from other frameworks too) that needs to be handled separately.

The aspect weaves into other public and private methods in the @Controller classes but not into the @RequestMapping methods specifically.

Note: i m not looking for a spring MVC specific solution ( unless it is the only option), I want to be able to weave into any type of classes and methods regardless of the framework without having to modify the running applications.

Here is my code.

```
public aspect MethodExecutionTimeAspect {

private CollectedData collectedData;

public MethodExecutionTimeAspect() {
    // some initialiation logic.
}


pointcut publicOperation() : execution(public * com.mycompany.myproject..*());

Object around() : publicOperation() {
    // do something
    Object ret = proceed();
     // do something.
    return ret;
  }
```

}

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.webapp.springmvc;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Resource(name="productService")
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/home.do", "/"})
public String displayHomePage(ModelMap map) {
    List<Product> featuredProducts = productService.getFeaturedProducts();
    map.put("featuredProducts", featuredProducts);
    return "homePage";
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointcut only matches methods without any arguments. The displayHomePage method takes a map parameter. Try

```
pointcut publicOperation() : execution(public * com.mycompany.myproject..*(..));
```

With the added `..` this pointcut will match any public methods within your specified package, regardless of how many arguments there are - if any.

Comment: Thanks. it was simpler than what I thought. not sure how i didn't notice the .. missing :)